# Why the covariance returned by MATLAB is only one vector?

Tags: matlab, covariance

If I have a random complex vector `Z` that's `2x1` in dimension, shouldn't the covariance return by MATLAB should be a `2x2` matrix? Instead, I get a single real valued covariance. According to [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_random_vector), when you have a `nx1` vector, the covariance should be in `nxn`. Any idea on this?

```
Z=[-0.0117 + 0.0032i; -0.0109 + 0.0046i]
C=cov(Z)
```

The `C` I obtained is `1.3261e-06`. I expected a `2x2` matrix.

Comment: MATLAB assumes the data is represented as row vectors not column vectors so `cov` interprets your input as two 1D samples . To get 2x2 covariance the  input should have 2 columns. Furthermore one sample says nothing about the variance of the underlying distribution, you need at least two samples to say anything about how the data varies (intuitively obvious).

Answer (score 0):

As per official Matlab documentation concerning the [cov function][1]:

```
C = cov(A) returns the covariance.
If A is a vector of observations, C is the scalar-valued variance.
```

The Wikipedia article you linked describes what you are attempting to obtain, but you can't assume that Matlab is implementing the same functionalities in the same way.

On a side note, it doesn't surprise me that the returned covariance is not meaningful. If you don't provide enough variables and enough observations, you can't estimate a covariation.